# MPMoviePlayerController stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video "movie.mov". When I try to read from my Xcode project with MPMoviePlayerController, it works perfectly. When I try to read from the url "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov", it works perfectly well. But! When I put this video on my NAS server, I get a link in the form: "http://myServer.com/file.php?id=3261c359e84a235d0761b182e445c28c6" and the video does not read.

**However, when I paste this link with VLC, Chrome or Safari, it works. So it's good link..**

So what's the problem?

```
//Work!
NSString* path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];

//Work!
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

//Not Work!
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[http://myServer.com/file.php?id=3261c359e84a235d0761b182e445c28c6][1]"];

MPMoviePlayerController mMoviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [mMoviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mMoviePlayer.view];
    [mMoviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
```

(Of course, I used the url one after the other)

When that did not work, the player starts but nothing happens.

If there is someone who has a solution, help me!

Edit :

I just sent a .m3u8 file on my NAS server. And I can read it. So as .mp4 .mov can not be read?

Comment: Can you show log of your url

Comment: When i copy paste your url in safari it doesn't work..

Comment: your url (not work) has only .mov, .mv4, etc. video or not?

Comment: It's an local url... I do not have the right to use a 192.168 address .. I put myServer.com. The actual link is: http://192.168.1.109/wfm/file.php?id=3261c359e84a235d0761b182e445c28c6a78600b8d352321797ab53fda781afe429e87e1f6b907f2e9ade802b8a068610f17326df73d68e4272143

Comment: Yes, The url points to movie.mov